# I can't figure out why the javascript generated <tr> elements aren't being styled by my stylesheet

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm trying to make a table with the background color alternating for every other row element. The styling seems to work for the row elements already in the html code, but when I generate some more rows using javascript, the new rows aren't styled and I can't figure out why. Any help would be appreciated.

```js
/* class Definitions
     *******************/
    class ladder{
        constructor(){
            this.data;
        }
        async getLeaderBoard(){
            try{
                const ret = await fetch(`https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://aoe2.net/api/leaderboard?game=aoe2de&leaderboard_id=3&start=1&count=10`);
                this.data = await ret.json();
            }
            catch(error){
                console.log(error);
            }
        }
    }
    
    //table DOM functions
    const renderCell = player => {
        const markup = `
        <tr class="player-entry">
            <td>${player.rank}</td>
            <td>${player.rating}</td>
            <td><a href= "">${player.name}</td>
            <td>${player.games}</a></td>
            <td>${Math.round(100*player.wins/player.games)/100}</td>
        </tr>`;
    
        document.querySelector('.leaderboards').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', markup);
    };
    
    const renderTable = leaderBoard =>{
        leaderBoard.forEach(renderCell);
    }
    
    
    
    
    
    /***********************
    /*MAIN
    /***********************/
    
    /*store data in window*/
    const state = {};
    
    /*
     * Fetch the data and save in state array
     */
    const dataFetcher = async () =>{
        
        //store the ladder object in state array
        state.AOELadder = new ladder();
    
        //load ladder from api
        await state.AOELadder.getLeaderBoard();
    
        //update to UI
        renderTable(state.AOELadder.data.leaderboard);
    }
    
    dataFetcher();
```

```css
.leaderboards{
        width:80%;
        text-align: left;
        margin-left:3rem;
        margin-top:3rem;
        line-height: 1.4rem;
        border:#888888 solid 1px;
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    
    .leaderboards .title{
        border-bottom:#888888 solid 1px;
        background:#222222;
        color:#fff;
        height:2rem;
    }
    
    .leaderboards a{
        text-decoration: none;
        color:#fff;
    }
    
    .leaderboards .player-entry{
        background: #999999;
        border-bottom:#888888 solid 1px;
        color:#fff;
    }
    
    .leaderboards .player-entry:nth-child(odd){
        background: #222222;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title> Practice Fetching API Data </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <table class="leaderboards">
            <tr class="title">
                <th>Rank</th>
                <th>Rating</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Games</th>
                <th>Win Rate</th>
            </tr>
            <tr class="player-entry">
                <td>565</td>
                <td>1500</td>
                <td>dummy-entry</td>
                <td>1000</td>
                <td>55%</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="player-entry">
                <td>565</td>
                <td>1500</td>
                <td>dummy-entry</td>
                <td>1000</td>
                <td>55%</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="player-entry">
                <td>565</td>
                <td>1500</td>
                <td>dummy-entry</td>
                <td>1000</td>
                <td>55%</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <script type="text/javascript" src= "./main.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Can you add jsfiddle or jsbin of your code, it would be easy to debug your code.

Comment: You are missung tbody in document.querySelector('.leaderboards tbody').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', markup);

Comment: I'll look those up, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `table` tag automatically appends `tbody` element (TABLE must have one or more TBODY elements) to wrap the rows. Therefore, you need to add the row inside the body in order to determine alternation.

Just update your inserting script to this:

```
document.querySelector('.leaderboards').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0].insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', markup);
```

Comment: It worked, and I'll read some more about that as well. Thanks for taking the time to help!!!